# Oracle Advanced Queuing - Subscriber Message Tracking

Tags: oracle, oracle-aq

How does Oracle Advanced Queuing track which messages that a subscriber has dequeued for a multiconsumer queue?

The USER_QUEUE_SUBSCRIBERS table tracks the subscribers per queue.  I can't find a table/view though that tracks the state of the subscriber for a given queue (e.g. what was the last message that the subscriber dequeued?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query the `AQ$<your_queue_table>.MSG_STATE`. The `AQ$<your_queue_table>.MSG_STATE` has an entry for each subscriber for each message.

```
select queue, consumer_name, deq_txn_id, deq_time, deq_user_id, 
 user_data, msg_state
  from aq$MC_QUEUE_TABLE
  where queue = 'MC_QUEUE';
```

In example my queue table is `MC_QUEUE_TABLE` and my queue is `MC_QUEUE`.

The MSG_STATE takes:

- **READY** - The message is ready to be processed, i.e., either the delay
- **RETAINED** or **PROCESSED** - The message has been successfully processed (dequeued) but will remain in the queue until the `retention_time` specified for the queue while executing `dbms_aqadm.create_queue` has been reached.
- etc.

Let's assume that we have 2 messages (msg1, msg2) and 2 subscribers (sub1, sub2). And sub1 has already dequeued the msg1.
As the result we will see:

```
QUEUE                          USER_DATA MSG_STATE        CONSUMER_NAME                 
MC_QUEUE                       (msg1)    READY            SUB2          
MC_QUEUE                       (msg2)    READY            SUB2          
MC_QUEUE                       (msg1)    PROCESSED        SUB1           
MC_QUEUE                       (msg2)    READY            SUB1
```

Because of `retention_time`, you may not be able to see your processed messages.

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!